# PHP search with class and public function

Tags: php

How can i run search function? i cant display the any result with this code and i don't know how to handle this class and function.. i'm a newbie with this kind of code..please review my codes....thanks!!!

```
<?php
$txtsearch = $_POST['txtsearch'];

class BlogController{

    public function search($txtsearch){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","sample_db");

        $display_query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_blogs` WHERE id='$txtsearch' ";
        $result = $mysqli->query($display_query);
    }

}

     if(isset($_POST["btnsearch"])){
        echo BlogController::search();
    }  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="create.php"> Create New Blog</a><br>
    <form action="function.php" method="post">
        <input text-align:right type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="search">
        <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search">

    <table border="1" width="60%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">ID</th>
                <th width="20%">Title</th>
                <th width="20%">Author</th>
                <th width="40%">Content</th>
                <th width="15%">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($blog = $result->fetch_object()): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $blog->id?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->title?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->author?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->content?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit.php?blog_id=<?php echo $blog->id;?>">Edit</a>
                    <a class ="btn_del" href="delete.php?blog_id=<?php echo $blog->id;?>">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile?>
        </tbody>

    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".remove-btn").on('click',function(){

            var is_confirm = confirm("Do you want to delete record?");

            if(is_confirm){
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            }

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class BlogController{

        public $txtsearch;

        function __construct($search) {
            $this->$txtsearch  = $search;
       }

        public function search(){
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","sample_db");

            $display_query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_blogs` WHERE id='$this->$txtsearch' ";
            $result = $mysqli->query($display_query);
            return $result;
        }

}
```

Create an instance and then call the function search

```
$myclass = new BlogController($_POST['txtsearch']); //pass value to the construct function
print_r($myclass->search());  // will return an array
```

Comment: please echo your query and check whether it's working

Comment: i mean echo your query dude... and check whether it's working properly or not?